# Android studio compileJava.options.debugOptions.debugLevel

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to configure gradle to include debug info in my apk so as when a report is sent to google play console, i can see the exact line and not "Unknown source".
I've tried with

```
compileJava.options.debugOptions.debugLevel
```

but it needs java plugin to be applied which conflicts with android plugin.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you